# Как сформировать запрос из двух таблиц SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

На Microsoft SQL Server есть две таблицы :
tab1 со столбцами - Модель, Тип, Цена.
tab2 со столбцами - Производитель, Модель.
Задача в том, чтобы выбрать минимальную цену каждого типа продуктов каждого производителя.
Вывести Производитель, Модель, Тип, Цена.

Понимаю, что простейшая задача, но из-за болезни совсем не соображает голова. Максимально просто подскажите, пожалуйста, чтобы понять логику.

Comment: Обычная нумерация в группе при правильной сортировке и выбор первой записи для каждой группы. CTE, ROW_NUMBER().

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но у меня задание для совсем начального уровня, где даже не используется нумерация.

Comment: Это и есть начальный уровень. С использованием современных средств.

Comment: @Borkau, Когда задаете вопрос, необходимо предоставить "Минимальный воспроизводимый пример".
Для справки: Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Для вашего сценария это означает следующее:
(1) DDL и образец вставки данных, т.е. CREATE table(s) плюс операторы INSERT, в SQL.
(2) Что вам нужно сделать, т.е. логика и ваш SQL код пытающийся ее реализовать.
(3) Желаемый результат на основе примера данных в #1 выше.
(4) Ваша база данных (СУБД) и ее версия.